# Unity drop items enemy sprite size problem

Tags: unity

how can i make items drop infront of the enemy without getting hidden under the enemy sprite due to the size of different enemies. I would also like to spread the drop items

How currently it is
[image]

How i would like it to be
[image]

My code:

```
public void TakeDamage(int damage)
{
    int dist = 10;
    Vector3 spawnPos = transform.position + transform.forward * dist;
    GroundItem.Create(new Item(3, 1), spawnPos);

    health -= damage
}

public class GroundItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Item item;
    [SerializeField]
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer = null;

    public static GroundItem Create(Item item, Vector3 position)
    {
        GameObject groundItemGO = Instantiate(GameManager.Instance.GetData.GetAssetDatabase.GetPrefabByName("GroundItemPrefab"), position, Quaternion.identity);
        GroundItem groundItem = groundItemGO.GetComponent<GroundItem>();
        groundItem.SetItem(item);
        return groundItem;
    }

    private void SetItem(Item item)
    {
        this.item = item;
        spriteRenderer.sprite = item.data.icon;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you not just make `dist` larger?

Comment: Yes, hur then i got the problem being items to far away from smaller creatures

Comment: Answer edited to include @DMGregory's suggested fix. Let me know if it workes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Sprite bounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite-bounds.html) to get the rough size of your sprite.
In your enemy class,

```
float spriteSize; 

void Start(){
    Sprite Sprite = GetComponen<SpriteRenderer.().Sprite; 
    spriteSize = Vector3.magnitude(sprite.bounds.extents);// get this only once for efficiency
}

public void TakeDamage(int damage)
{
    int dist = 10;
    Vector3 spawnPos = transform.position + (-1*transform.up) * (dist*spriteSize);
    GroundItem.Create(new Item(3, 1), spawnPos);

    health -= damage
}
```

EDIT:

As pointed out in the comments `transform.forward` will be *into* the game's third dimension, entirely not what you want. `-1*transform.up` (down direction) should work

Comment: It still creates the item center of the enemy

Comment: What is the value of spriteSize?

Comment: 256x256. I get the magnitude of 1.8

Comment: 1.8 is non-zero, you might need to increase the value of `dist` but I can't see why that wouldn't work? what is the value of `spriteSize` for different sprites?

Comment: It didn't help increase the distance. Seems stuck on the center

Comment: Oh, hang on. Is `Create` a function you wrote? and does `Item(3,1)`  inherit from monobehavior? I think i might know what your problem is

Comment: Yes, 3 is item id and 1 is aning. Then spawnPos is the position where it shall spawn. It inherit from monobehavior

Comment: Could you perhaps add the code for the `Create` function to your question. I'll alter my question to explain why but it's generally advised you don't call a naked `new` on monobehavior objects - they have a dedicated way of creating them and using `new` can cause problems

Comment: Sorry for late answer, i've updated the main post with the function

Comment: Note that in the default Unity setup for a 2D game, transform.forward points *into* the screen, so you might want to displace along -transform.up instead.

Comment: Cheers guys, now it works :)